# Escaping metacharacters in Regex with MongoDB (via mongolite package)

Tags: r, regex, mongodb, mongolite

I was querying some data via R by using mongolite and I faced a strange problem, which I eventually solved even though I cannot understand in deep way the **why** it works. I wanted to filter all fields with 78.20 string (no matter what's next; so the regex works fine for me).

```
\\ query in mongo: works
db.getCollection("exper").find({"index.tgh": /^78\.20.*/ })

\\ query via mongolite: works but only with the 4 backslashes
query <- '{"index.tgh": {"$regex": "^78\\\\.20.*"}}'
ext_1 <- database$find(query = query, fields = '{}')
```

Now, I understand that I had to escape the dot, so I placed a backslash in mongo. At the same time, I understand I have to escape the backslash itself in R and then I placed another slash.

What I cannot understand is why I needed two more backslashes to let the query work properly via `mongolite`... a third one I can foresee as escape the escaping (which in R is itself a special characther). Still do not understand the fourth one.

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't seem like an R question, but you  need to use "\\" to create a single escape character because the first of them essentially get stripped off by R which uses the same escape character. If you really wanted two escapes to be passed through to the regex engine, you might need 4 escapes in mongodb, assuming it behaves like R. Notice that in R the quoted double backslash is only recognized as a single character: `nchar("\\")` returns `1`